# Angular JS - Cannot load data from multiple modules

Tags: angularjs, module

I'm having problems when trying to use multiple modules in Angular JS. I cannot use more than 1 module, it seems like Angular doesn't recognize the code. I'm willing to use a tree view + flex grid on an application but the tree doesn't shows up, just the flex grid. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something on moduling but I don't know what... Here is the code:

index.htm

```
<html ng-app="app">
<script src="js/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

<!-- Flex Grid !-->
<script src="js/flexygrid/controllers/FlexControllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/flexygrid/directives/FlexDirectives.js"></script>
<script src="js/flexygrid/misc/FlexBlock.js"></script>  
<!-- Tree !-->
<script src="js/tree/controllers/TreeControllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/tree/directives/TreeDirectives.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

main.js

```
var app = angular.module('app',['flexyLayout.directives','tree.controller']);
```

FlexControllers.js

```
function (angular) {
    "use strict";
    angular.module('flexyLayout.mediator', ['flexyLayout.block']).
    controller('mediatorCtrl', ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', 'Block', function (scope, element, attrs, Block) {
        ...
    }
```

FlexDirectives.js

```
function (angular) {
"use strict";
angular.module('flexyLayout.directives', ['flexyLayout.mediator'])
    .directive('flexyLayout', function () {
        ...
})(angular);
```

FlexBlock.js

```
(function (angular) {
"use strict";
angular.module('flexyLayout.block', [])
    .provider('Block', function () {
        ...
    } 
})(angular);
```

TreeControllers.js

```
(function(){  
    angular.module('tree.controller',['angularTreeview']).controller('TreeCtrl', function($scope){
        ...
    }
})();
```

TreeDirectives.js

```
(function(){
angular.module('angularTreeview',[]).directive('treeModel',function($compile){
        ...
    }
})();
```

Comment: The plunker dont work correctly (only see "Not Found"). Additional its hard to find mistakes in minified js code ... break it down to find the error. Nobody wants to read so many code to help you

Comment: please simplify demos to replicate problem only... far too many files and too much code in demo to quickly assess what's going on

Comment: Alright, I edited my post with (part of) the code that I think I'm not using correctly